# Troubleshooting "The service “ipaliases” appears to be down." In WHM

Tags: cpanel, whm

**Background**

Last night I was having some trouble with my server when I added a new IP address. I tried but could not get it routed in my WHM. In the beginning I tried adding it from the,

*Show or Delete Current IP Address menu of WHM.*

I created a new `Cpanel Account` and chose the IP as the dedicated IP for that account. When I could not get it routed I took three steps,

```
1. I released it from the account

2. Released the IP from the server (AWS)

3. Deleted the account
```

Then I tried to delete it from the WHM menu mentioned above. When I try to delete it I get this same message over and over again,

[image]

Since then I have routed a new IP and everything started working fine. But I cannot remove the old IP still. Now to top that off I have received this high priority message in my email from `WHM`

[image]

**Question**

I am wondering if these two things are related and I can not come up with a way to troubleshoot this.

What are the proper steps I can take to safely remove the IP address that shows inside of the *Show or Delete Menu*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When making configuration changes to the server at some point I changed the server's main IP address for a brief time. This made `WHM` think the `main IP` was the one that I was unable to delete `10.0.1.175`. In order to resolve this I followed these steps,

**1. I  ran the /scripts/mainipcheck script to make sure that the main network interface was mapped to the proper IP.**

**2. Once that resolved the issue I ran the /scripts/build_cpnat scrip just to make sure that all private IP addresses were mapped to the proper external IP addresses.**

At this point I was able to remove the IP address that was not part of my network and everything continued to work as normal.